# How to modify EMSR when capacity for each fare class is different

Tags: optimization, yield

In the normal EMSRa and EMSRb algorithms (EMSR= expected marginal seat revenue), each fare class is utilizes exactly 1 unit of capacity (for eg. one seat on a plane).

But I have a similar problem for Revenue Optimization, where each fare class can occupy a different levels capacity, for eg. some fare classes might utilize 2x the amount the capacity.

How would you modify the EMSR algorithm such that along with the Fare and the Demand forecast (mean, std). you are also given a capacity *c_i* occupied by each fare class *i* and given you have some fixed total capacity *C*

How to modify EMSR when capacity for each fare class is different?

Comment: Sorry, this question may be outside the scope of Quant Finance.

Comment: @noob2 thanks, do you have a suggestion as to where I can post this?

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about quant finance (=> or.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes please close it, I've asked this on OR SE, thanks!